# No sound output when running jsyn on raspberry pi (Raspbian Jessie)

Tags: raspberry-pi, jsyn

I've started writing a java synthesizer using the jsyn library. It works well in windows and osx, but when I run it on Raspbian. When starting the program i notice some activity in the headphone output though, it starts to output some silent noise, but no clear loud sawtooth wave like it does on Windows and OSX. Which sound device is the correct one to select as output when starting the synthesizer if I want to use the headphone jack? There are 4 avaliable when I run the AudioDeviceManager.getDeviceCount()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to know which of the 4 devices to use. This example will list them by name and also indicate which one is the default input or output.

https://github.com/philburk/jsyn/blob/master/tests/com/jsyn/examples/ListAudioDevices.java

It is also possible that the CPU cannot keep up. Try just playing a single oscillator. A sine wave is good because then you can easily hear any click or distortion. Here is an example that does that:

https://github.com/philburk/jsyn/blob/master/tests/com/jsyn/examples/PlayTone.java

Comment: Yes, I get sound when I run the PlayTone example.  I guess it's the CPU then. On my Macbook with 2.9 GHz i7 it does use like 35% total CPU power and the Pi does only have 900MHz. Do you have any suggestions  for optimizing CPU usage when using JSyn?

Comment: What's the most CPU friendly way of alternating between different oscillator waveforms? Right now I have 8 of them running simultaneously (2xSine, 2xSawtooth, 2xSquare, 2xTriangle for VCO/LFO) and just switching the connections when pressing a button. Is there any way to "disable" them while keeping the objects in memory? And which units in JSyn are the most demanding ones? I'm also using the FilterFourPoles and around 20 utility units like Multiply/Add.

Comment: If you disconnect() a unit's output then it will not get executed. The SawtoothOscillatorDPW sounds almost as good as the SawtoothOscillatorBL but it much less CPU. You can sometimes eliminate Add units by just connecting multiple outputs to an input. They will get added together automatically.

Comment: Also PlayTone just used the default output so that may also be why it works. Try each possible output to see if one works with your synth.

Comment: Thanks! Are the filters demanding? I disconnect the oscillators every time I switch waveform, so that shouldn't be stealing any country power. I'm already using the SawtoothDPW but I will try using the non-band limited oscillators to see if that makes any difference. Good advice on the Add units, I may be able to cut down on those. By the way, is it possible to make use of several cup cores somehow? The raspberry have four of them and it would probably make a lot of difference if the synth could split up the work. I suspect that it's a challenge to make these things thread safe though.

Comment: > PlayTone uses 35% of CPU on a Macbook
That test is too short. You are seeing the Java launcher. Increase the sleep time from 4 seconds to 60 seconds and then watch 'top' or the Activity Monitor. User CPU load will drop down below 1% on a Mac while still playing the tone. Check out "tests/com/jsyn/benchmarks/BenchJSyn.java" for better benchmarks.